# Unwanted display of collection object after iterating through the collection in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have a block which iterates through a collection of tags and creates links for them.

The issue I have is that after it returns the formatted links, it also returns the entire ActsAsTaggableOn object as text. I only wish to display the formatted links.

Here's my partial:

```
    <h4>Tag Cloud</h4>
<div>
  <%= tag_cloud @tags, %w[s m l ] do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag), :class => css_class %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Image below shows how it is returning both the formatted links and the collection object - which I don't want to display.

[image: Just want the links not the object that returns afterwards]

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In erb, `<%= %>` will display whatever that line of code returns. While `<% %>` just executes the line of code.

Change `<%= tag_cloud @tags, %w[s m l ] do |tag, css_class| %>` to `<% tag_cloud @tags, %w[s m l ] do |tag, css_class| %>` and the object won't be displayed.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would be something simple.